# Windows Service Installation Failure : Unable to get Installer types

Tags: c#, .net, service, windows-services, installutil

I've developed a `Windows Service`, and I've done the following :

1. Added the `Installer`
2. Made sure the `ServiceName` property in `ServiceInstaller`1 matches my service name
3. Set the correct parameters
4. Changed startup in Project properties to  `serviceName.Program`
5. Started VS command tool as an administrator.

However, even after all this, the installation of the service, using `Installutil` fails, giving the following error :

> Installing assembly 'C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestLicenseService\TestLicenseService\bin\Debug\TestLicenseService.exe'.
>   Affected parameters are:
>      logtoconsole = 
>      logfile = C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestLicenseService\TestLicenseService\bin\Debug\TestLicenseService.InstallLog
>      assemblypath = C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestLicenseService\TestLicenseService\bin\Debug\TestLicenseService.exe
>   An exception occurred while trying to find the installers in the C:\Users\\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\TestLicenseService\TestLicenseService\bin\Debug\TestLicenseService.exe assembly.
>   System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoaderExceptions property for more information.

All relevant dependencies are present in the correct folders, and yet it does not install the service. What could be the issue?

Using VS2013 and Windows 8.1.

Kindly advise.